# pwrite() on OSX 10.6 not honoring 64-bit offsets

Tags: c, macos, osx-snow-leopard, posix

I seem to be having an odd problem with `pwrite()` on OSX 10.6.8 when attempting to write to an offset beyond 2GB. I keep catching a `SIGXFSZ` signal, meaning that the file-size limit has been exceeded.  Ignoring the signal doesn't help because `pwrite()` will then simply return `EFBIG`.

It seems that OSX does not support the explicit `open64()` and `pwrite64()` functions.  It also seems that `sizeof(off_t)` is a proper 8-bytes in size, meaning that `pwrite()` should take a 64-bit offset.  Is there a flag I'm missing when calling `open()`, or some OSX-specific setting I should be passing for my file-descriptor to `fcntl()` to enable large-file support?

Finally, when I check `getrlimit()`, with the `RLIMIT_FSIZE` option, it says that both the current and the max file-size limit is `9223372036854775807` bytes.  So that doesn't seem to be preventing me from writing large files via `pwrite()`.

Has anyone else had problems with `pwrite()` under 64-bit OSX?

---

**EDIT:** Per request, I'm adding the code that calls `pwrite()` ... note that this code is inside a write-thread:

```
for (int i=0; i < data->iterations; i++)
{
    unsigned char* ptr = data->buffer;
    int temp_buff_size = data->buff_size;
    int offset = i * data->buff_size;

    while(temp_buff_size > 0)
    {
        int temp_bytes_written = pwrite(data->fd, ptr, temp_buff_size, offset);

        if (temp_bytes_written >= 0)
        {
            temp_buff_size -= temp_bytes_written;
            ptr += temp_bytes_written;
            offset += temp_bytes_written;
        }
        else if (errno == EINTR)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            perror("Write thread exiting");
            write_thread_finished = 1;
                return (void*)-1;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling it inside a loop since it's my understanding that `pwrite()` is not guaranteed to write all the data requested, and so I need to make sure that the data I am requesting be written is actually written to disk, and if less bytes are written, then I properly offset into the buffer I'm writing to get the rest of the buffer onto the disk.  The role of `data->iterations` is just passing to the thread information on how many times to write the buffer to disk ... this is part of a bandwidth test, so I'm trying to write a large file to see how fast it can be written to disk.  The only problem is I'm not able to pass an offset larger than 2GB to `pwrite()`.

Comment: Why don't you show us the code that calls `pwrite`?

Comment: I don't know about OSX, but isn't `int` still kept at 32 bits even on 64-bit systems? So when the signed integer rolls over to negative, you try to write at a negative offset?

Comment: As @JoachimPileborg notes and as `pwrite`s signature states, you should use `size_t` for the size and `off_t` for an offset.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That was it ... Put that down as an answer and I'll accept it as the official answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On OSX `int` is still kept at 32 bits even on 64-bit systems. So when the signed integer rolls over to negative, you try to write at a negative offset.

**Edit:** The correct type, as per the manual, is `off_t` which should be of correct size and signedness whether the underlying OS is 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: @R.. It was easy when I saw the code. Specially since I had my self mixed int/long on a 64-bit system earlier today. :)

Comment: BTW this answer would be better if you mention that the variable `offset` should have type `off_t`.